# Is it possible to route to a PROJECT_ID.appspot.com url using gRPC endpoints on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to quickly setup a gRCP-endpoint instance on GCP but they seem to be [only accessible from inside GCP](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc-dns-configure).

The thing is you can have an endpoint that is managed and it will have a PROJECT_ID.appspot.com URL.

Also, can a gRPC endpoint be publicly accessible ? Is it recommended ?

Answer (score 0):

[pRPC](http://nodir.io/post/138899670556/prpc) is one solution, as I am using golang.

Following [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/3KYVLrNJiT4) I might use it. It allows to do gRPC on appengine, without the streaming capabilities, which is fine for me now.

Hope someone has a better answer.

Comment: fyi, I did not go there as appengine go is on golang 1.4, too painful to use